# Dynamically append element jquery and javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

**Now:**
It makes hello button well, but when I click it, nothing happens.

**Question:**
I want to see alert or console.log

How can I do that?

My Code:

```js
class ArtObj {
  constructor(string) {
    this.text = string
  }

  append_content(wrapper) {
    var div = $("<a id='hello' href='#'>hello</a>")

    div.find("#hello").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.text)
      alert(this.text)
    });

    wrapper.append(div)
  }
}

art1 = new ArtObj("string_zz")
art1.append_content($("#artifact_wrapper"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="artifact_wrapper"> </div>
```

Comment: You can only bind the event after you appended it to the wrapper

Comment: @AlonEitan that's not correct.  You can bind events to a jquery object before appending.  You can't bind events to DOM elements that don't exist, but that's (subtly) different.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks for clarifying @freedomn-m and sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A better way to create a new jQuery Element is by passing the Element options as the second parameter

> [jQuery DOCS- Creating New Elements](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements)
> As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn)
> can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter

- Define the click inside the Element options - no need to attach unnecessary listeners to other elements like `"body"` or document, etc.
- Would be nice to define the `this.$el` right at *init* inside the constructor, that way, your *append* function would do exactly what it says.
- Makes more sense to call a function by what it does, and that's `something.append_to(somewhere)`, not `append_content`. Actually, you don't need that method at all if you already use jQuery.

```js
class ArtObj {
  constructor(string) {
    this.text = string;
    this.$ = $("<a>", {
      id: "hello",
      text: "hello",
      href: "#",
      click: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.text)
      }
    });
  }
}

const art1 = new ArtObj("string_zz");
art1.$.appendTo("#artifact_wrapper");
```

```html
<div id="artifact_wrapper"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since it makes no sense to create a class that generates a reusable component with a fixed ID, makes more sense to allow the user of your class to pass into the desired bits and pieces:

```js
class ArtObj {
  constructor(options) {
    this.$ = $("<a>", options);
  }
}

const art1 = new ArtObj({
  id: "hello_1", // ID must be unique!
  text: "hello",
  href: "#",
  click: (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("string_zz");
  }
});
art1.$.appendTo("#artifact_wrapper");
```

```html
<div id="artifact_wrapper"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

therefore, given the above, seems unnecessary to use a `class` at all:

```js
$("<a>", {
  id: "hello_1", // ID must be unique!
  text: "hello",
  href: "#",
  click: (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("string_zz");
  },
  appendTo: "#artifact_wrapper"
});
```

```html
<div id="artifact_wrapper"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do `div.find` because your `div` variable itself is an `a` tag with id `hello`. Just add event on variable `div` directly.

*I would rename variable to `a`, so there is no confusion.*

```js
class ArtObj {

  constructor(string) {
    this.text = string
  }

  append_content(wrapper) {
    var div = $("<a id='hello' href='#'>hello</a>")

    div.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.text)
      alert(this.text)
    });

    wrapper.append(div)
  }

}

art1 = new ArtObj("string_zz")
art1.append_content($("#artifact_wrapper"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="artifact_wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this. Your script was not in proper order and jQuery find function need to be used on parent elements.

```js
class ArtObj {
  constructor(string) {
    this.text = string
  }

  append_content(wrapper) {
    wrapper.append("<a id='hello' href='#'>hello</a>");
    wrapper.find("#hello").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.text)
      alert(this.text)
    });
  }
}

art1 = new ArtObj("string_zz")
art1.append_content($("#artifact_wrapper"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="artifact_wrapper"> </div>
```